# Do you need android sdk to use appium with real android devices?

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

Do you need to install android sdk to use appium with real android devices or only if you plan to use an android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android SDK and Java JDK are required whether you want to automate an emulator or a real device.

Refers to [Appium doc](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/android-uiautomator2/#basic-setup)

> Follow the steps below based on whether you want to automate an emulator or a real device.